# How to build linux-modules-extra deb package from kernel tree?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I am following `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel` to build a custom kernel from the `5.18` source tree from `kernel.org`. It created a `linux-headers-*.deb` and `linux-image-*.deb` and `linux-libc-dev*.deb` packages after I build. However I am not seeing a `linux-modules-extra*.deb` package. I am curious to know on how can I get this or can I build it from the source tree?

Comment: you might not have such a file. Your modules might be included in the "linux-image-*.deb" file. Just install the header and image file and then check if the modules were also installed.

Comment: @DougSmythies , Thanks. Is that the linux-modules-extra*.deb is distributed by third party or distros and not buildable from kernel source tree?

Comment: No. linux-modules-extra is a Canonical thing. Simple mainline build just ends up with the two .deb files that one needs to install. You end up with all the same stuff, in the end.